# How to make an HTTP request with the value for the header 'Authorization' coming from a readable store which is set by another HTTP request

Tags: svelte, svelte-store

My initial objective was importing the store Token and use it's value directly in the FinancialInstitution class instead of passing it as a parameter to the function, but none of the usage has worked as expected, get() nor subscribe().

My objective is to make a single request to the **listFinancialInstitutions()** only after having the token store set.

And what's currently happening is that the request is made two times, the first one with the initial value of empty string and then the second time with the result of the response.

What am I missing to obtain the behavior that I want?

So I've created a service called token.js:

```
export class Token {
    async createToken() {
        const init = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            mode: 'cors'
        };
        return await fetch(`${middleware}/token`, init)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
}
```

The store.js:

```
import {readable} from 'svelte/store';
import {Token} from './services/token';

const tokenService = new Token();
export const token = readable('', set => {
    tokenService.createToken().then(res => set(res.access_token))
});
```

The service to obtain the list:

```
export class FinancialInstitution {
    async listFinancialInstitutions(token) {
        // if (typeof token !== 'string') {
        //     return;
        // }
        const init = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            },
            mode: 'cors'
        };
        return await fetch(`${middleware}/financial-institutions`, init)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
}
```

The svelte component:

```
<script>
    import {FinancialInstitution} from '../services/financial-institution';
    import {token} from '../store';

    let financialsPromise;
    const financialService = new FinancialInstitution();
    token.subscribe(t => {
        financialsPromise = financialService.listFinancialInstitutions(t);
    })
</script>

<section>
    <h2>Financial Institutions</h2>
    {#await financialsPromise}
        <span>⏳ Fetching the list of financial institutions </span>
    {:then financials}
        <ul>
            {#each financials.data as financial}
                <li>{financial.id}</li>
            {/each}
        </ul>
    {:catch error}
        <p>Sorry but there's no data </p>
    {/await}
</section>
<style>
    ul {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    ul li {
        list-style: none;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialize your token store with an empty string, subscribed components will immediately receive that value, this is the reason why you see this initial request with an empty string (i.e. the value of the token before the store gets updated with an *actual* token).

To prevent this, you can test the value being returned by the store and act accordingly:

```js
    token.subscribe(t => {
        financialsPromise = t ? financialService.listFinancialInstitutions(t) : undefined;
    })
```

and to complement this, you will also want to wrap the render of your promise inside a conditional:

```
    {#if financialsPromise}
        {#await financialsPromise}
            <span>⏳ Fetching the list of financial institutions </span>
        {:then financials}
            <ul>
                {#each financials.data as financial}
                    <li>{financial.id}</li>
                {/each}
            </ul>
        {:catch error}
            <p>Sorry but there's no data </p>
        {/await}
    {/if}
```

Comment: Indeed it works this way but is there another alternative to handle the value of the token store in the service and not in component, instead of passing as param to the function?

Comment: @disciplus Stores are reactive by design, so if you are set on using a store, the only way to do what you are asking would be to initialize the store with the correct value right away, upon its creation. This means you would have to have already acquired the token beforehand, basically making the whole operation synchronous rather than asynchronous, not a good idea imo. If reactivity is not desired and you only want a handy way of making the token value available across components, consider using [context](https://svelte.dev/docs#setContext) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Answer above is correct. I made a simple example to demonstrate how the subscribe is executing twice.

https://svelte.dev/repl/b1fa28b592854900a62dd4b18ca5d6b9?version=3.44.2